# Example $\limsup_n A_n\neq\liminf_n A_n$ on probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have seen lots of examples on $\mathbb{R}$, but can anybody give me an example of a probability space and a sequence of events such that $\limsup_n A_n\neq\liminf_n A_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the space consist of the sequences of fair coin flips and $A_n$ be the event that flip $n$ is heads. With probability 1 there are infinitely many heads so $\limsup A_n$ has probability 1, but with probability $1$ there are also infinitely many tails, so $\liminf A_n$ has probability $0$. Or let the space consist of a single point $\omega$, let $A_{2n}=\mathbb{1}(\{\omega\}),A_{2n+1}=\mathbb{1}(\emptyset)$ and then $\limsup A_n=\Omega,\liminf A_n=\emptyset$. Btw $\mathbb{R}$ can be a probability space, e.g., when you endow it with the borel $\sigma$-algebra and normal distribution law.

Comment: what does the notation $1(\{w\})$ means?

Comment: I am using $\mathbb{1}(A)$ to denote the indicator of the event $A\subset\Omega$, i.e., the function that maps $\omega\in\Omega$ to $1$ if $\omega\in A$ and to 0 when $\omega\notin A$. The font isn't reproducing what I usually get in latex with "mathbb{1}", though.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ random variables and let $A_n = \{X_n = 1\}$. Then 
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n\right) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_n\right) = 1, $$ while $$
\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n\right)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_n\right) = 0.
$$

Comment: on this case $\limsup A_n=\Omega$ and $\liminf A_n=\emptyset$?

Comment: No, for example $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\subset\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n $$ and $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c\not\subset\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n. $$ These events must have probability zero, but they may be nonempty.